# Specify different addon plans for dev/test/prod environments

Tags: heroku, continuous-integration, cloud, production-environment

Is it possible on Heroku to specify different addon plans depending on environment we're in?

I have some test environments, where what I need is the lowest possible PostgreSQL plan (hobby tier). But for production I need a more powerful one.

I'd like my infrastructure to be assembled entirely from the `app.json` file, but it looks like it can't differentiate production from testing etc.

Is there something I miss, or maybe I approach that the wrong way?

Answer (score 0):

You can provide environment-specific settings [via a top-level `environments` object](https://devcenter.heroku.com/articles/app-json-schema#environments). Each key in this object completely replaces the values provided at the top-level for

In this case, something like

```
{
  "addons": [
    "heroku-postgresql:premium-0"
  ],
  "environments": {
    "test": {
      "addons": [
        "heroku-postgresql:hobby-dev"
      ]
    }
  }
}
```

should do the trick.

Comment: yeah, but as documentation says, only "test" is supported, and as far as I understand "test" here means CI instances created on-demand , not the persistent app instances just with relaxed spec requirements

Comment: @MichalOstruszka, it looks like you're right. I thought this was more flexible.